# How to split text (poem) into lines (string/char[]) and finding last word of each one

Tags: c++, string

I have a poem, for example this:

```
    Roses are red
    Violets are blue
    Sugar is sweet
    And so are you
```

separeted only with /n
and i need to get each line's last word, for last word finding a friend suggested using this:

```
string lastWord(string line)
{
    return line.substr(max(line.rfind(" "), 0));
}
```

But what about splitting text into lines?

Answer (score 3):

> But what about splitting text into lines?

The answer depends on where the text is initially: if the entire text is in a file, use `ifstream`; if the text is in a `string`, use `stringstream`. In both cases, use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) in a loop to extract lines from the text one-by-one:

```
string poem = "Roses are red\n\
Violets are blue\n\
Sugar is sweet\n\
And so are you";
stringstream ss(poem);
string line;
while (getline(ss, line)) {
    cout << lastWord(line) << endl;
}
```

Also, your `lastWord` function has an off-by-one error: you should simply add one to the result of `rfind`, rather than using `max`, like this:

```
string lastWord(string line)
{
    return line.substr(line.rfind(" ")+1);
}
```

This will remove the initial space from the word being returned.

Comment: `while (std::getline(ss, line)) { ... }`?

Comment: Is that sarcasm? With your rep I was a bit suprised you had not posted it. If not then glad to help! (and +1)

Comment: @hmjd No, it's not sarcasm at all: I've been out of C++ coding for 10+ years, so I forgot a few tricks here and there.

Answer (score 0):

Call `substr` in a loop as long as you have a newline.

And remember that newline can be different depending on platform, `'\n'` on Linux/OSX and `"\r\n"` on Windows.

Comment: That's why you normally read text files in text mode - to get the newlines handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `split` function. See also: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split